# Getting error as 'Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed' after executing unit test

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, async-await, xunit

I have below code which navigates from one page to other using Navigation Service in Xamarin forms.
On clicking on Observation button it executes ObservationsCommand as shown below.

```
public Command ObservationsCommand => new Command(async () => await OnObservationsCommandAsync());
```

After clicking on Observation button it navigates to next page passing the selected data to the navigation service as shown

```
private async Task OnObservationsCommandAsync()
            {
                ObservationDetailsParameter selectedData = new ObservationDetailsParameter
                {
                    Cage = DisplayedCage,
                    Dossiers = DossierList.SelectedItems
                };
                await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<ObservationDetailsViewModel>(selectedData);
            }
```

Below is the code for unit test

```
 [Fact]
    public void TestOnObservationsCommandAsync()
    {
        var mockNavigationService = new Mock<INavigationService>();
        var mockCageDetailsService = new MockCageDetailsService();
        var mockObservationDetailsService = new MockObservationDetailsService();
        var mockSettingsService = new MockSettingsService();
        Cage _displayedCage = new Cage { Id = 11 };
        Dossier _dossier1 = new Dossier { Id = 841 };
        var _dossierList = new SelectableItemCollection<Dossier>
        {
            _dossier1
        };
        _dossierList.SelectAll();
        var cageObsViewModel = new CageObsViewModel(mockNavigationService.Object, mockCageDetailsService, mockSettingsService);
        var mockObservationDetailsParameter = new 
Mock<IObservationDetailsParameter>();

        mockObservationDetailsParameter.Setup(x => 
x.Cage).Returns(_displayedCage);
        mockObservationDetailsParameter.Setup(x => x.Dossiers 
).Returns(_dossierList.SelectedItems );

        cageObsViewModel.DisplayedCage = mockObservationDetailsParameter .Object .Cage ;
        cageObsViewModel.DossierList = _dossierList;

        // Act
        cageObsViewModel.ObservationsCommand.Execute(null);
        mockNavigationService.Verify((s) => s.NavigateToAsync<ObservationDetailsViewModel>(mockObservationDetailsParameter.Object));
    }
```

However after executing this test i get error as 'Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed.'
Will you please help?

Comment: Hi, are you interested in testing InternalNavigateToAsync or testing that OnObservationsCommandAsync actually called the navigation service with the right parameters. I can provide an example for the latter if that's what you need.

Comment: I am interested in OnObservationsCommandAsyc calls navigation service with correct parameters. Will you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a unit test I have to verify navigation after successful login.

```
[Fact]
        public async Task ValidCredentials()
        {
            //Mock login -> false
            var authenticationServiceMock = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>();
            authenticationServiceMock
                .Setup(s => s.Login(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

            LoginViewModel viewModel = new LoginViewModel(authenticationServiceMock.Object);

            await viewModel.InitializeAsync(null);

            viewModel.UserName.Value = "johann@mail.com";
            viewModel.Password.Value = "1234!Maaaa";

            viewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);

            navigationServiceMock.Verify((s) => s.NavigateToAsync<HomeViewModel>());
        }
```

As I am using AutoFac and my ViewModelBase gets the NavigationService instance by itself this is my test setup:

```
public LoginViewModelTests()
        {
            ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            navigationServiceMock = new Mock<INavigationService>();

            navigationServiceMock.SetReturnsDefault<Task>(Task.FromResult(0));

            builder.RegisterInstance<INavigationService>(navigationServiceMock.Object);

            ViewModelLocator.RegisterDependencies(builder);
        }
```

If it is not clear enough let me know and we can review it to better adapt to your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have written below test case.
           cageObsViewModel.ObservationsCommand.Execute(mockObservationDetailsParameter);
            mockNavigationService.Verify((s) => s.NavigateToAsync<ObservationDetailsViewModel>(mockObservationDetailsParameter));

But it gives me error as
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed.

Comment: It is hard to say without taking a look on how the command is coded and the test is setup. Are you sure the mocknavigationservice is being by the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes it is used. I have updated the code given above.

Comment: I think the problem is that the verify method will assert that the parameter received by the NavigateToAsync method is exactly mockObservationDetailsParameter.Object which is not true because the method creates a new instance. You can use It.Is< IObservationDetailsParameter>(p => <<SomeAssert>>) instead of mockObservationDetailsParameter.Object. You can see full working example here https://github.com/johannperez/UnitTestingSamples

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It worked for me. Thanks again :)